CORS error when trying to get GitHub authorization from the frontend
I am developing a REST API in node.js, I am trying to make a request from a frontend to an endpoint on my local server (http://localhost:8080/auth/github). I'm using JavaScript to make the fetch request, but I'm encountering a CORS error.
The code I am using to make the request is the following:
async function createCart() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/auth/github", {
      mode: "no-cors",
      method: "GET",
    });

    console.log(response.ok);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Authentication Error", error);
  }
}



However, when running this function from my frontend, I am receiving the following error:

I've tried adding no-cors mode to the request, as well as installing cors and importing it into my api config, but this time I get a false from the console.log(response.ok). How can I fix this CORS error and make the request from my frontend to my local endpoint successfully?
Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Instead of setting no-cors on your initial request to your own server, make sure your server sends proper CORS headers. In this case, Github needs to "call your server back" at the end of the oauth negotiation, so you'd better make sure your server allows that call to go through =)
